# CSS transition doesn't happen in Firefox or IE

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a simple style like:

```
li, a {
    display: inline-block;
}
li {        
    transition: top 0.3s;
}
li:hover {
    position: relative; top: 3px; 
}
```

which is supposed to work with some icons in a menu so that they sink down when you hover over them. It works fine in Chrome, but not in IE or FF. What could possibly be wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and IE require that you specify an initial attribute for the animated property.

So:

```
li, a {
    display: inline-block;
}
li {        
    top: 0;        /* ADD THIS! */
    relative: 0;   /* This is important too or the item will pop back   
                      instead of transition*/
    transition: top 0.3s;
}
li:hover {
    position: relative; top: 3px; 
}
```